# C#: Why don't generics use the most generic type it can when we don't specify one?

Tags: c#, generics

For example I now created a this tiny class:

```
public static class FileSystemInfoComparers<T> where T : FileSystemInfo
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> FullName
    {
        get { return new FullNameComparer(); }
    }

    private class FullNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        public bool Equals(T x, T y)  { return x.FullName == y.FullName;   }
        public int GetHashCode(T obj) { return obj.FullName.GetHashCode(); }
    }
}
```

I would like it if I could just do

```
var comparer = FileSystemInfoComparers.FullName;
```

and have an instance of `IEqualityComparer<FileSystemInfo>`, since I didn't specify any type and FileSystemInfo is the most generic type T can be. With no type constraint the default type could for example be object or something.

Maybe not the best example, but anyways just got curious here :p

Comment: Interesting proposal. What would it do with interface constraints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like a recipe for trouble to me.

In particular, you could easily create a non-generic class called `FileSystemInfoComparers` with a static property of the same name, and suddenly your code would mean something *completely* different.

I'd rather keep things simple. (Generics are complicated enough already, and type inference in particular is pretty hairy.)

Comment: "Sounds like a recipe for trouble to me.".  That tickled our dev department, keep those one-liners coming Jon :-) +1

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting idea and it could definitely work but consider that it would only work in cases where the generic type argument is constrained with a concrete type.

The .NET compilers are very good at *type inference* but tend to shy away from making any assumptions.  I don't see any reason why this couldn't be done except that it would only work in a small number of highly-specific instances.  Since it has no *general* purpose I would imagine that Microsoft would be less inclined to make a change to support it.

Comment: Not really: System.Collections.Generic.List<T> doesn't have a constraint, so System.Collections.Generic.List could be equivalent to System.Collections.Generic.List<object>

Comment: @Niki: Perhaps I should have said "it would only do something useful".  A List<Object> is not particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could possible do this by having a helper class that has the default type you want set.  But what you are asking for currently cannot be done in C# 3.0.

Comment: Hm, good idea actually... could maybe just create a class inheriting from it or something. Although that wouldn't be possible for static classes. And would require kind of rewriting various constructors etc for non-static ones...